# How to uncomment blocks code in emacs

Tags: emacs, comments

I am using emacs with the major mode "Java/L Abbrev" activated. When I type `M-x comment-region` or `M-x uncomment-region` the desired effects happen in the editor. But I am getting tired of typing this out every time.

I have found that I can type `C-c C-c` and comment a region. I want to find a similiar way to uncomment a region. I go to the emacs docs:

https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Comment-Commands.html

And it says to give the `C-c C-c` command a negative argument to uncomment lines. How do I do this? or is there a better way?

Answer (score 14):

Please try `M-;`, which is bound by default to `comment-dwim`.  I think this should do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is how to use `C-c C-c` to uncomment the region.

@AaronHarris answered your question about using a negative prefix arg.

But I think you misread the doc of `comment-region` (which CC mode binds to `C-c C-`). It does **not** uncomment the region. It deletes a certain number of comment characters.

To *uncomment* the region you use `C-u` - a plain prefix arg (no explicit number) to uncomment the region.  `C-h f comment-region` says:

> comment-region is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
>   `newcomment.el`.
>
> It is bound to menu-bar edit region comment-region.
>
> `(comment-region BEG END &optional ARG)`
>
> Comment or uncomment each line in the region.
>
> **With just `C-u` prefix arg, uncomment each line in region `BEG .. END`.**
>
> Numeric prefix `ARG` means use `ARG` comment characters.
>
> *If `ARG` is negative, delete that many comment characters instead.*
>
> The strings used as comment starts are built from `comment-start`
>   and `comment-padding`; the strings used as comment ends are built
>   from `comment-end` and `comment-padding`.
>
> By default, the `comment-start` markers are inserted at the
>   current indentation of the region, and comments are terminated on
>   each line (even for syntaxes in which newline does not end the
>   comment and blank lines do not get comments).  This can be
>   changed with `comment-style`.

So the answer is to use **`C-u C-c C-c`**.

And FWIW, `comment-region` is much better than `M-;` (`comment-dwim`) for commenting and uncommenting the region. It lets you nest and unnest comment blocks any number of levels.

Answer (score 4):

`comment-dwim` (DWIM stands for "Do What I Mean") is bound to `M-;` by default and works differently depending on whether or not the region is active (and sometimes what mode you're in)

From the emacs help page for `comment-dwim`:

```
comment-dwim is an interactive compiled Lisp function in
‘newcomment.el’.

It is bound to M-;.

(comment-dwim ARG)

Call the comment command you want (Do What I Mean).
If the region is active and ‘transient-mark-mode’ is on, call
‘comment-region’ (unless it only consists of comments, in which
case it calls ‘uncomment-region’).
Else, if the current line is empty, call ‘comment-insert-comment-function’
if it is defined, otherwise insert a comment and indent it.
Else if a prefix ARG is specified, call ‘comment-kill’.
Else, call ‘comment-indent’.
You can configure ‘comment-style’ to change the way regions are commented.
```

Comment: For me M-; only works when the text that needs to be commented out is highlighted, otherwise the command will simply add a comment at the end of the line - in case that's helpful for anyone.

Comment: @Tiberius yes.  In emacs, having the line highlighted is called "having the region active".

Comment: Thank you for your prompt clarification! That was the missing puzzle piece for me here - very enlightening. Maybe this will help someone else who is trying to switch to Emacs, like me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

TLDR: Use `C-- C-c C-c`; i.e., prefix your command with "control-hyphen"

To give a negative argument to a command, you need to call either the `negative-argument` command or the `universal-argument` command, supplying a negative argument.  (Try `C-h f` for more information on these.)

The `negative-argument` command is bound to keys `C--`, `M--`, and `C-M--`, so all of these will work as prefixes; generally, you'll use the one that's most convenient to type for any given command.

The `universal-argument` command is bound to `C-u` and accepts its argument immediately after that, so you can also do `C-u -`, optionally followed by zero or more digits (e.g., `C-u - 5 3 9`); that one is overkill here, but good to know about.

Finally, [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html) is the section of the Emacs manual that discusses this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Why not mapping the `uncomment-region` command to a key? It's not really what you were asking for (previous answer are better for this) but it's a way to stop typing `M-x uncomment-region` every time

like this (with the key binding you want)

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-u") 'uncomment-region)
```

Documentation about key binding can be found here:
[Commands for Binding Keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Binding-Commands.html)
[Customizing Key Bindings](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Bindings.html)

Here is a map of command:
[Map of command](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/refcards/pdf/refcard.pdf)

You can use `C-h k` (`M-x describe-key`) to show what command is bind to a particular key (so you're sure to not erase it) and `C-h f` (`M-x describe-function`) will show you a description of the function + its binding.

Answer (score -1):

- First, select the region
- To comment, use

  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> comment-region
- To un-comment, use

  <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> uncomment-region

Credits: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/1kklgl/command_to_uncomment_entire_comment_block/